# Need dotnet regex to replace an underscore (_) with 0%

Tags: javascript, .net, regex

We have a card being scanned in which has `ZZZZ_ss16` printed on the card and scans as `ZZZZ0%ss16`. The users are initially registering the cards with the wrong number due to the misprint. Card reprint would be great but isn't an option.

I have a javascript regex which should do the job but am having trouble translating this to work with dotnet.

```
s/^(\w{4}).(\w{4})/\10%\1/
```

We just need the first 4 characters, replace `_` with `0%`, followed by the last 4 characters.

Hope someone can assist.

Comment: Tried ^(\w{4})_(\w{4})$ with $10%$2 and ^([A-Za-z0-9_]{4})_([A-Za-z0-9_]{4})$ with ${1}0%$2 on http://www.regexstorm.net/tester but they don't work.
Any ideas??

Comment: This is almost right but still having trouble capturing the first 4 char

Comment: This is almost right but still having trouble capturing the first 4 char

http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5bA-Za-z%5d%7b4%7d)_(%5bA-Za-z0-9%5d%7b4%7d)&i=ZZZZ_ss16&r=0%25%242

this shows as 0%ss16  
not the expected ZZZZ0%ss16

Comment: Looks like ^(\w{4})_(\w{4})$  with ${1}0%$2 works. Testing later.

Thanks for all your help guys :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use

```
^(\w{4})_(\w{4})$
```

and replace with `$10%$2`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oQ7rD4/2)**

For `.net` use this

```
var pattern = "^([A-Za-z0-9_]{4})_([A-Za-z0-9_]{4})$";
var template = "ZZZZ_ss16";
var replaceWith = "${1}0%$2";
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/Qod4VI)**

Comment: Keith Hall already provided the [correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37429496/3832970).

Comment: If you need to match the same text with `\w` in JS and .NET, just use `new Regex(@"^(\w{4})_(\w{4})$", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);`. See [*ECMAScript Matching Behavior*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#ECMAScript).

Comment: I think the general rule is "Accept if it works best for you, upvote if it is helpful to you".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regex that will capture the first four characters into capture group 1 and the last 4 characters into capture group 2, and then perform a replace to output group 1, followed by `0%`, followed by group 2.

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"^(\w{4})_(\w{4})$");
var input = "ZZZZ_ss16";
var output = pattern.Replace(input, "${1}0%$2");
// RESULT: ZZZZ0%ss16
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/cykSFu)

It is necessary to escape the digit after the `$`, otherwise it will get interpreted as the 10th capture group. Recommended reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This [outputs `ZZZZ%0ss16`](http://ideone.com/EJDpyB), you swapped the `%` and `0` in the replacement string.